# Usar una función de una clase, dentro de la misma en PHP

Tags: php, funciones, class

hace unas horas vengo estudiando sobre las clases en PHP, y tengo una duda que no logro encontrar una respuesta en Google, así que espero que alguien me pueda ayudar por acá.

Yo lo que quiero es, llamar a una función que tengo dentro de una clase, en otra función dentro de la misma clase, como puedo hacer eso?

Por ejemplo:

```
class clase {
    public function a(){

    }

    public function b(){
        // Usar la función a() acá.
    }
}
```

Espero que me haya explicado bien.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?, ¿exactamente qué resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y no funciona como en la mayoria de lenguajes hacer a()???

Comment: Me parece que lo único que falta es que sea así: `$this->a();` dentro de la función `b`

Answer (score 0):

Para usar una funcion dentro de otra puede hacer esto

```
class clase {
    public function a(){

    }

    public function b(){
         self::a();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto.

```
<?php
class My_clase {
    public function a($param){
        echo $param;

    }

    public function b(){
        $this->a("Echo de a desde b");
    }
}

$instance = new My_clase();
$instance->b();
?>
```